# Text underline crossing whitespace

Tags: css, sass, whitespace, underline

I've been attempting to build the following (figma): [image]

As it stands i've tried padding, margins, psudeo elements, whitespaces and I'm pretty stuck on what to do. You can see its possible to have the underline styles on the icon, but when I create distance from 'ID', the underline gap appears. I need the icon to stay as far away as it is here but also keep the underline crossing.
[image]

HTML:  Please note 'input-row' cannot be styled in this instance as it's used across other elements

```
<div class="input-row">
    <a class="link" href="#">Acceptable Forms of ID    <i class="fas fa-share-square"></i></a>
</div>
```

```
.fa-share-square{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $secondary-five;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: underline dotted $secondary-five;
    text-underline-offset: .5rem;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```

```
.link{
    color: $secondary-five;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: underline dotted $secondary-five;
    text-underline-offset: .5rem;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: apply the underline to input-row instead

Comment: This won't work, the input-row isn't an element I can style as it needs to be used in other places and this a tag needs to be able to drop anywhere on our form. Also, when I tried to apply it to the div out of curiosity, nothing show'd up. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, will check it out :)

Comment: @Martin It seems the idea could only seek to add a slight extra space for the underline. I had attempted a white-space: pre on the icon, but it wasn't nearly enough. Good idea though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove `text-decoration` from your `css` and update as follows. Also set `text-decoration:none` for the `.link` class. Finally set border-bottom for the class `input-row` and `width:fit-content`. I am using `color:red`, you can use of your own choice.

HTML code:

```
<div class="input-row">
    <a class="link" href="#">Acceptable Forms of ID    <i class="fas fa-share-square"></i></a>
</div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
.fa-share-square {
            font-size: 0.75rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: red;
            font-size: 1rem;
            /*text-decoration: underline dotted red;
            text-underline-offset: .5rem;
            text-decoration-thickness: 2px;*/
        }

        .link {
            color: red;
            font-size: 1rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            /*text-decoration: underline dotted red;
            text-underline-offset: .5rem;
            text-decoration-thickness: 2px;*/
        }

        .input-row {
            border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
            width: fit-content;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but as mentioned in the OP I want this to work without the use of a container styles. If at all possible.

Comment: If your container just contains the data you mentioned then it is simple and nice to do it like this. Also if data increases or decreases border will extend and decrease accordingly due to use of "width: fit-content"

Answer (score 2):

You have a ***input-row*** container around these 2 elements,

Add the underline to the container, use margin and or padding to get it right under the text.

Comment: This won't work, the input-row isn't an element I can style as it needs to be used in other places and this a tag needs to be able to drop anywhere on our form. Also, when I tried to apply it to the div out of curiosity, nothing show'd up. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Revised Answer

It appears that I had misunderstood your original request. I now understand that you want the underlined (dots) to appear uniformly for the anchor *including the space between the text and the Font Awesome icon*.

This is more simple than the previous answer.

You will first need to remove the default text-under line from HTML anchors, this is done in the `a.link` CSS below.

Then you style the anchor as an inline-block/block level element (which it is by default), and style a **`border`** rather than **`text-underline`**, because text-underline won't (and symantically shouldn't) activate on a *lack* of text (whitespace). You can also customise the gap between the text and the underline using `padding`.

So:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-row">
    <a class="link" href="#">Acceptable Forms of ID    <i class="fas fa-share-square"></i></a>
</div>
```

And then you set your CSS styling thus:

CSS:

```
.fa-share-square{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $secondary-five;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

    a.link {
        color: #900;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        border-bottom: 2px dotted #00F;
    }
```

Full example:

```css
 .fa-share-square{
        font-size: 0.75rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        color:  #900;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    
    a.link {
        color: #900;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-bottom: 3px; /* Set the border distance from the text */
        border-bottom: 3px dotted #00F; /* Set the border style */
    }
    
     .fa-share-square {
      width: 3rem;
      height: 1rem;
      padding-left:1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>(Extra CSS put in place to show the Font Awesome Icon part)</p>
    <div class="input-row">
        <a class="link" href="#">Acceptable Forms of ID
        <i class="fas fa-share-square">ICON</i></a>
    </div>
```

Manual Reference for [**CSS Border-bottom**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom).

Comment: No no, I wanted it to span across the gap

Comment: @DecisiveDevelopment sorry I misunderstood your question. Please see my revised answer which I think fixes your issue. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had a stroke of genius in the shower. Line spacing.

At first I tried this on the Icon, but the spacing moved the underline to the right, so I needed to apply it to the letter beforehand.

Here you can see my changes and result.

```
<div class="input-row">
    <a class="link" href="#">Acceptable Forms of I<span>D</span> <i class="fas fa-share-square"></i></a>
</div>
```

```
.link{
    color: $secondary-five;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: underline dotted $secondary-five;
    text-underline-offset: .5rem;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span{
        letter-spacing: 12px;
    }
```

Some minor issues with the dots overlapping each other at certain spacing values, but this is a lot closer to a solution than anything else

[image]

Comment: Interesting workaround, but the fundamental symantics is that you ideally should not be using `text-decoration` for non-text; as I showed I think `border` can work just as well and avoid the need for workarounds.